# What is a weekly lesson plan?

Tags: english, teaching, terminology

What is a Weekly Lesson Plan?

The context in Poland, Young Learners of Grade-3. ESL.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the info into the question. I think you have two questions; the first is terminology question, which I think is fine. The second is quite a broad question about planning weekly language lessons. Maybe these two could be asked as separated questions?

Comment: Can you please split up this question into two separate ones? I.e. one about the concept as such and another one about resources to help create lesson plans?

Comment: @Tsundoku, done.